# Why does "too [adjective] a [noun]" require the determiner to come *after* the adjective?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, big-mess-construction

> Example: *John is too good a person to do something like that.*

If you can say John is "a very good person to do something like that", then why not "a too good person to do something like that?"

Why does "too good" have to come before the determiner in this kind of construction? And parenthetically, is there a term for this particular syntax?

Comment: It's actually "John is too good *of* a person..." but the *of* is frequently omitted.

Comment: You might find this helpful:  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/usage-of-indefinite-article-and-too

Comment: _Too_ is a negative quantifier and requires an infinitive to define what's being negated; e.g, _He's too poor to buy a ticket_ means 'He is so poor that he doesn't have enough money for a ticket'. So **a too good person*, if it were grammatical, would mean someone who is so good that `something is not possible` (whatever that might  be).

Comment: English is full of idioms which seem illogical. Perhaps it is the result of the way the language has developed, a bit like the British built environment. But *too convoluted a process* it would be now to revise everything so that all roads ran straight, and the cities were more ergonomically sized and located. .

Comment: @JohnLawler I think perhaps *a too nice person* does exist - and they are different to *too nice a person*. Occasionally someone will say - I don't trust that guy, he seems 'too nice' to me - he is *a too nice person*, as opposed to *too nice a person to...'.

Comment: Except you can't say **a too nice person*. [Maru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MpLBf993xs) can do that, in Japanese English, but not us.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: any references for that? *?Too good of a person* has no rational basis, and I would consider it wrong in all cases (unlike, say, *too much of a good person*)

Comment: @TimLymington, nope...just my life-long usage of my native language.  However, if you read my one and only question, you'll see that I apparently make stuff up from time to time. :-/

Comment: The  structure "too difficult a task"  is an example for the vagaries of English, and you find such queer things in any language.  I myself would be very  interested to understand how such a structure came into being.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does "too good" have to come before the determiner in this kind of construction? And parenthetically, is there a term for this particular syntax?

I can't really answer the 'why' question, because it's simply the way English works. Somehow, English has this construction, and grammarians use the term '**pre**determiner' or '**pre**determiner modifier' to describe such adjectival phrases as 'too good' in your example, apparently because they come before determiners (the indefinite article *a*).

Of course, there are many different types of predeterminers as well, as in:

> *John is **such** a good person.*

But the kinds of adjectival phrases in question are limited to adjectival phrases having the construction starting with a small number of degree modifiers such as: *too*, *as*, *so*, *how*, *this*, *that*, etc. As long as adjectival phrases start with one of these degree modifiers and are followed by *a*, they can be predeterminers.

> *John is **as good** a person as Jane.*
>
> *John is **so good** a person that he can't do something like that.*
>
> *John is **as good** a person as Jane.*
>
> ***How good** a person is John?*
>
> *John is **this good** a person.*
>
> *John is **that good** a person.*

Since they're predeterminers, you need the indefinite article *a*. Hence, you can't predetermine a plural noun or a non-count noun.

> **They're too good people to do something like that.*
>
> **This is as good coffee as that.*

Comment: “They’re too good people to do that” doesn’t strike me as impossible. It does sort of break down a little if I think about it too much, but at first blush it seems fairly natural. Now adding in that strange, pleonastic _of_ that some people use in these constructions, however – that yields an unquestionably impossible construction to me (“*They’re too good of people to do that”).